# error in installing Github Project Cascading/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, vagrant, puppet

I started installing [vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster](https://github.com/Cascading/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster) github project, but there are some errors happening and it can not end the installation.

**When I did "vagrant up"**

```
sina@linux:/media/sina/passport/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster$ sudo vagrant up
Bringing machine 'hadoop1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'hadoop2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'hadoop3' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'master' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> hadoop1: Importing base box 'cascading-hadoop-base'...
==> hadoop1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> hadoop1: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster_hadoop1_1409806559206_53275
==> hadoop1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> hadoop1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    hadoop1: Adapter 1: nat
    hadoop1: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> hadoop1: Forwarding ports...
    hadoop1: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> hadoop1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> hadoop1: Booting VM...
==> hadoop1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    hadoop1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    hadoop1: SSH username: vagrant
    hadoop1: SSH auth method: private key
==> hadoop1: Machine booted and ready!
==> hadoop1: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    hadoop1: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    hadoop1: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    hadoop1: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    hadoop1: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    hadoop1: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    hadoop1: your host and reload your VM.
    hadoop1: 
    hadoop1: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    hadoop1: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> hadoop1: Setting hostname...
==> hadoop1: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> hadoop1: Mounting shared folders...
    hadoop1: /vagrant => /media/sina/passport/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster
    hadoop1: /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests => /media/sina/passport/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster/manifests
    hadoop1: /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0 => /media/sina/passport/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster/modules
==> hadoop1: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> hadoop1: Running Puppet with datanode.pp...
==> hadoop1: stdin: is not a tty
==> hadoop1: warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/File[/etc/motd]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}0c3e6f224eb6cf6fbff62de3067eaef9'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/srv/zookeeper]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/File[/root/.ssh]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/File[/root/.ssh/config]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}880efd788ff2d77bf3989a13a9e0344a'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/File[/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}622c3becafba74b1f4f1267436cbd28b'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/Ssh_authorized_key[ssh_key]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/Exec[apt-get update]/returns: executed successfully
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/Package[openjdk-6-jdk]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Base/File[/root/.ssh/id_rsa]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}a9e4aa776fe92555716b7963488838f6'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/Package[avahi-daemon]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/File[/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}bd8d4eda789abe26c48c1f1f74d19551' to '{md5}e45468ec4a7369471c5101403f5b8f87'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/File[/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf]/mode: mode changed '0644' to '0600'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/etc/profile.d/hbase-path.sh]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}06cf529d2063f3060bfca646dd2d1a18'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/File[/etc/avahi/hosts]/content: content changed '{md5}186990ae1edac95a88dbef6a36a07716' to '{md5}c90385145a2d6900d7d027bd87cd8ff0'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/File[/etc/avahi/hosts]/mode: mode changed '0644' to '0600'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/Service[avahi-daemon]: Triggered 'refresh' from 4 events
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/etc/profile.d/hadoop-path.sh]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}da4327f03f22df21251fece99b4fda68'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/tmp/verifier]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}ee3850511912c0b432c98426be818253'
==> hadoop1: err: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[download_grrr]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0/hadoop/manifests/init.pp:37
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[download_checksum]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[download_checksum]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[download_hadoop]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[download_hadoop]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hbase/Exec[download_hbase]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hbase/Exec[download_hbase]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/File[/etc/hosts]/content: content changed '{md5}28728fdc2cb16bf53da7ba1988a7e978' to '{md5}c90385145a2d6900d7d027bd87cd8ff0'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Avahi/File[/etc/hosts]/mode: mode changed '0644' to '0600'
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[verify_tarball]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[verify_tarball]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hbase/Exec[unpack_hbase]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hbase/Exec[unpack_hbase]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/opt/hbase-0.96.2-hadoop2/conf/hbase-site.xml]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/opt/hbase-0.96.2-hadoop2/conf/hbase-site.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[unpack_hadoop]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[unpack_hadoop]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/opt/hbase-0.96.2-hadoop2/conf/regionservers]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/opt/hbase-0.96.2-hadoop2/conf/regionservers]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/slaves]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/slaves]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/stop-all.sh]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/stop-all.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[hadoop_conf_permissions]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[hadoop_conf_permissions]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/masters]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/masters]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/start-all.sh]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/start-all.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/opt/hbase-0.96.2-hadoop2/conf/hbase-env.sh]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hbase/File[/opt/hbase-0.96.2-hadoop2/conf/hbase-env.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/prepare-cluster.sh]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/prepare-cluster.sh]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Group[hadoop]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/User[hdfs]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/srv/hadoop/]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/srv/hadoop/namenode]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/srv/hadoop/datanode/]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/User[yarn]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/User[mapred]/ensure: created
==> hadoop1: 
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/mapred]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/mapred]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/yarn]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/yarn]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/hadoop]: Dependency Exec[download_grrr] has failures: true
==> hadoop1: warning: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/File[/opt/hadoop-2.3.0/logs/hadoop]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> hadoop1: notice: Finished catalog run in 1838.19 seconds
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

It gives an error in exec download_grrr

```
==> hadoop1: err: /Stage[main]/Hadoop/Exec[download_grrr]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0/hadoop/manifests/init.pp:37
```

The exec command that this error is referring to is in [/modules/hadoop/manifests/init.pp](https://github.com/Cascading/vagrant-cascading-hadoop-cluster/blob/2.5/modules/hadoop/manifests/init.pp)

```
  exec { "download_grrr":
    command => "wget --no-check-certificate http://raw.github.com/fs111/grrrr/master/grrr -O /tmp/grrr && chmod +x /tmp/grrr",
    path => $path,
    creates => "/tmp/grrr",
  }
```

I Downloaded the grrr file myself and it worked. So there is no problem in downloading the file itself

**the grrr file contains :**

```
#!/bin/bash

# author: André Kelpe <efeshunderelf at googlemail.com>
# licencse: Apache v2

GRRR_WGET_OPTIONS="--user-agent grrr/1.0"

# find out our region and yes, you can get this as csv file. How cool is that?
GEOIP_REGION=$(wget -qO- freegeoip.net/csv/ | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr -d '"'| awk -F, '{print $2}')

# classic confusion between geoip db and apache mirror list
if [ $GEOIP_REGION == "gb" ]; then 
    GEOIP_REGION=uk
fi

MIRRORLIST_FILE_NAME=$(mktemp)

# download the latest mirror list from apache. we ignore the last
# sync times and hope for the best...
wget -qO- http://www.apache.org/mirrors/mirrors.list | grep -v '^$' \
    | grep http | grep -v ' 0$' | grep -v '^#' > $MIRRORLIST_FILE_NAME

# use US as the default region. apache does the same in their scripts...
REGION=us

# check if there is a mirror in our region
if grep -q " $GEOIP_REGION " $MIRRORLIST_FILE_NAME; then
    REGION=$GEOIP_REGION
fi

# finally download it all
wget $GRRR_WGET_OPTIONS $(grep " $REGION " $MIRRORLIST_FILE_NAME | shuf | head -1 | awk '{print $3}')/$*

retval=$?

# clean up after ourselves.
rm $MIRRORLIST_FILE_NAME

exit $retval
```

So because some of other exec commands require the download_grrr exec, they are skipped because of failed dependencies. How can I solve this error?

Comment: How long does it take to download `grrrr`? Note that the command didn't error out - it hit a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a timeout implies the file took too long to download from the server. You'll need to add a `timeout => 0` to that command, or a high enough value. Puppet's default timeout for exec is 300 seconds.

However, since it's downloading a quite small shell script there might be a networking issue with that URL it wgets. It's possible you were rate-limited or Github took long to respond when it tried to run that command.

The easiest way would be to manually fix it by doing:

```
vagrant ssh
wget --no-check-certificate http://raw.github.com/fs111/grrrr/master/grrr -O /tmp/grrr && chmod +x /tmp/grrr
exit
vagrant --provision
```

I just cloned that repo and ran vagrant up and it worked fine for me. It might have been a temporary network blip.